# Confusion about friction during pure rolling

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Friction comes into play with the relative motion between the surface and the points of the body in contact with it. In a perfectly rolling sphere, the instantaneous velocity of the bottommost point is zero, which means there shouldn't be any friction. 
But if there is not friction at all, why do we talk about the work of friction being zero during rolling?
Or, is there some friction after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero velocity doesn't mean no friction. The friction acting on a stationary object is called *static friction*. Friction arises when there is a relative motion *or* a tendency for the relative motion. So there is a tendency for the relative motion at point of contact in rolling motion. Therefore there is friction, which helps the rolling motion by providing torque. But the rolling friction overcomes this helping static friction, therefore rolling object gradually slows down.